# Switched power supply output voltage modification

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, voltage-divider, tl431

After days of research and experimentation, I was unsuccessful in modifying a power supply output voltage from 15.3V to 5V.

My work was focused on the output section of this switched mode power supply, which I sketched and is enclosed below and to which I will be referring.

[image]

My first attempt was to change R1 and R2 so that they are equal in value. This should have caused the TL431 to force the output voltage to 5V. I first tried R1=R2=20kΩ and then tried 3.9kΩ, both attempts yielded a stable ~8V output, not the 5V I expected.

My next attempt was driven by a suspicion that the voltage across the photocoupler was only ~1V. According to the spec, the nominal voltage should be 1.2V at a nominal 1mA. I therefore changed R4 to be 1.2kΩ (it used to be 2.2kΩ). That too did not change the outcome, I still got approx 8V at the output.

At this point I ran out of ideas. The only additional test I did was to disconnect the TL431 and photocoupler from the circuit as I was curious to measure the "raw" rectified voltage out of the low-voltage-side of the transformer. That voltage was fluctuating between 19V and 22V.

Any leads, tips or ideas would be much appreciated.

Here are a few more facts:

- I was not able to find out the value of the SMD capacitors C4 and C1. I also don't know the value of L1.
- The voltage across the TL43 (cathode to anode) measured 1.9V which i thought was suspiciously low, but did not know how to influence that value.

Thank you
Alon

Comment: R5 is too big, therefore the current through the optocoupler is too small. Try 100 Ohms. Also, increase R1 and R2 to 20kOhms again to lower the feedback loop's bandwidth, that'll help with stability.

Comment: You may need a minimum load for proper regulation.

Comment: What is the duty cycle of the switcher when the output is 15V?

Comment: What were R1 and R2 in the original design?

Comment: The original board had R1=20kΩ and R2=3.9kΩ which gave a Vout of 15.3V

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy, If I get my hands on an oscilloscope to measure the duty cycle, can you give me some leads on how that may help me resolve the issue at hand?

Comment: If a flyback converter is operating in CCM mode, ideally, Vout/Vin = N*D/(1-D). (see https://youtu.be/DnVTRwo9aiU ). Note, that for a fixed turns ratio N, the duty cycle alone fixes the ratio between Vout and Vin. If a flyback converter is operating in DCM mode, then ideally, Vout/Vin = D*sqrt(Rload*T/(2*Lm)). Note that in this case, that Rload _does_ affect the ratio between Vout and Vin for a fixed duty cycle, but the turns ratio N does not. There are a variety of things that might be conspire to make your output other than what you expect, but it will take some digging to find the cause.

Comment: While you are trying to get your hands on an oscilloscope, it would also help to see more of the circuit on the switching side of the flyback converter. There may be circuitry to protect the voltage across the switching transistor during flyback. There may be a load that keeps the supply in CCM at 15V output, but allows the supply to enter DCM at 5V. There may be something about the switching control that needs to be looked at. In short, more information means better chances of discovering issue.

Comment: https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/the-difference-between-ccm-and-dcm-explained#:~:text=Alternately%2C%20if%20tOFF%20lasts%20long,discontinuous%20conduction%20mode%20(DCM). There is the better explanation.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy, I've posted the full SMPS schematic and waveforms in a separate post [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/612559/smps-step-down-transformer-unexpected-waveforms?noredirect=1#comment1615340_612559) (mostly because I was not sure how to add more info into this post)

Comment: Did you try lowering R5 to 100 ohm's as suggested in 1st comment?